# How i can set IDENTITY_INSERT to On

Tags: sql-server, database, c#-4.0

I am getting the error while to insert values to database table:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ref_user' 
when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Please help me out ???

Comment: You could have spent less time googling and getting answer than asking here

Comment: @archil I have googled it much but did not find proper answer that is why i asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is that you are trying to insert in a table with Auto Increment field being used as primary ke.

In your command, you may set the `Identity_Insert On` and then `Off` after insertion. Something like:

```
new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON;
               Insert into yourtable .....;
               SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF;", yourConnection);
```

Comment: BUt i have put my stored procedure name after new SqlCommand("my stored procedure") ??

Comment: @AmmarAsjad - then your stored procedure is broken, and needs the above lines or (as I said in my answer), you need to modify the `INSERT` statements to stop trying to supply a value for the `IDENTITY` column in the table.

Comment: I also want to set ID identity column ON, how to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblename on
```

Answer (score 3):

try

syntax:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database. [ owner. ] ] { table } { ON | OFF }
```

Ex:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.your_table  ON;
```

**EDIT**:

Please note that when you specify the identity insert on.. you have to explicitly specify the  column list in the insert statement

**Example**:

```
create table test_identity (id int identity , val int)



SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.test_identity  On;
insert into test_identity (id,val) select  1,2
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.test_identity  OFF;
```

Comment: Where to try your suggested syntax??? in my stored procedure?

Comment: before inserting to the table .. you can set the IDENTITY_INSERT on like in my example .then insert the values to the table. please note that you have to specify the column list in the insert statement..

Answer (score 0):

If you're not familiar with this error, it's more likely that you're trying to supply a value for a column where you shouldn't.

Say you have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    Col1 varchar(10) not null
);
```

If you attempt an insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO T(ID,Col1) values (1,'abc');
```

You'll get the error you've posted. Usually, what you actually want to do is:

```
INSERT INTO T(Col1) values ('abc');
```

(And possibly retrieve the inserted value by `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` afterwards).

But to your question *as posed*, you would do:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT T ON;
INSERT INTO T(ID,Col1) values (1,'abc');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT T OFF;
```

---

You should, in general, *not care* about what values are being assigned to an `IDENTITY` column - they're magic values that happen to have a compact, numeric representation. But you should treat them as a black box. Problems tend to arise when you assign meaning to the numbers.